# Unable to start Genymotion virtual device, incompatible CPU

Tags: android, cpu, windows-7-x64, genymotion

The first time I ran Genymotion virtual device, it had worked. But when I tried running it today, I got this error message

[image]

What may have changed from the last time I used it? Will be grateful for any solutions that I can get. Thanks.

My Device Info:
Dell XPS L502X
Sandy Bridge motherboard
Intel Core i5-2410M @2.30 GHz
Windows 7 Professional 64-bit

Comment: Ok, I found out that this happened as VT-x was used by some other application in windows and VirtualBox could not use it. I was not able to find the application using VT-x, so I just disabled/unchecked "Enable VT-x/AMD-v" in the virtual device's Settings-> System -> Acceleration. Any better solutions for this?

Answer (score 34):

You need to turn virtualization on.

1. Reboot the notebook.
2. Instantly press F10 to enter BIOS settings (or F2 depending on your PC)
3. Check the settings and look for Intel Virtualization Technology (Aliases: Intel VT-x).
4. Turn it on then save and exit. You could use F10 to save and exit.

This will enable you to use virtualization and enable VirtualBox. Therefore your emulator will hopefully work.

Comment: Well I haven't tried this, but virtualbox said VT-x was used by some other application and to close that application, but I did not know which application was using it, so i just disabled or unchecked the "Enable VT-x/AMD-v" in the virtual device's Settings-> System -> Acceleration. So, do I have to turn it on ?

Comment: I'm not sure if this means that your VT-x is enabled or not.. but I got the same problem as yours before and that is how I solved it..give it a shot hope it works for you.

Comment: Need turn on virtualization in the bios and turn off Hyper- v feature

Answer (score 22):

I've solved my problem just turning off the Hyper-V on Windows Features.

Answer (score 19):

Another way to receive this message is because you are running another application that use VT-x like the Android Emulator from Android Studio. If you open Virtualbox and try to start the VM you will get this error message. Solution: **Close the other emulator and try again.**

Comment: This wokred for me, but what is the reason?

Comment: That was my case. Thank you a lot.

Answer (score 8):

For me the following worked:

Disable/uncheck "Enable VT-x/AMD-v" in the virtual device's Settings-> System -> Acceleration

Answer (score 8):

Execute the following command in `cmd` opened as administrator to disable `hyper-v` and then reboot the machine:

```
bcdedit /set hypervisorlaunchtype off
```

I don't know why disabling `hyper-v` from system preferences doesn't work for me, only the command works for me. Also I had to close `Docker` first to execute the command.

Comment: when i installed docker hyper-v disabled. and your command helped me that i enable it again ,thank you

Answer (score 5):

Solution for windows 10: Control Panel → Programs → Turn Windows components on or off.
Uncheck the Hyper-V option and click OK.

Answer (score 5):

in **ubuntu**

1-Reboot the notebook.

2-enter BIOS  (press F10 or F2 )

3-Check enable **Intel Virtualization Technology** and save and exit.

Answer (score 2):

I've also seen this exact same error dialog (for the first time ever) today after upgrading to the latest versions of both VirtualBox and GenyMotion. Nothing else on my system has changed. It's not the best answer in the world, but after trying a few other suggestions I came across, I found that simply cancelling the dialog and restarting the virtual Genymotion device (either via Android Studio or via the Genymotion console) resolved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

## Fix it in Virtualbox directly

1. Open VirtualBox
2. If you find a similarly named device "Inaccessible" or any other state than "switched off", stop it or remove it.
3. Start the device from Genymotion

---

4. Feel Happy :)

Answer (score 1):

I've seen this exact same error dialog on the first install. I changed my BIOS settings and it worked but after a month the same error occurred.

My solution:

1. Open VirtualBox Manager
2. Settings > Network > Promiscuous Mode
3. Change from "deny" to "allow"

Answer (score 1):

i just decreased the amount of base memory used by the machine in virtualbox manager **settings > System > Base Memory**  and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

In VirtualBox settings > System disable I/O, EFI, UTC and AMD-V.
And Settings > Network > Promiscuous Mode modify in all.

Answer (score 1):

I had to deactivate '**Memory Integrity**' of Windows 10 (1803) 'Core Isolation' Feature of **Windows Defender**. It is deactivated by default, and for some odd reason I had forgotten I had switched it on recently.

I also checked that in VirtualBox -> Your virtual machine -> Settings -> System -> Acceleration -> 'Enable VT-x/AMD-v' and 'Enable nested paging' are activated, Hyper-V is not installed and virtualization is turned on in BIOS.

There is an explaining article on HowToGeek explaining that aformentioned Memory integrity feature:
https://www.howtogeek.com/357757/what-are-core-isolation-and-memory-integrity-in-windows-10/

Answer (score 1):

I have solved this issue not just by enabling VT-x but also by enabling VT-d (Virtualization Technology for directed I/O) in BIOS

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it in VirtualBox:
Setting > System > Disable checkbox "Nested Paging"

Answer (score 0):

One more correct answer is that recent versions of Genymotion support only 64bit CPU and that will cause the same error.

Answer (score 0):

For me the solution was to close another emulator which was open.

Answer (score 0):

None of the solution worked for me. This is what solved the issue:

1. Turn on Hyper-V in Windows Features.
2. Restart PC.
3. Turn off Hyper-V in Windows Features.
4. Restart PC.

Boom!

Answer (score -1):

I Had The Same Problem And I Solve It By Turning Off The Hyper -v In Windows Programs And Features. Now I Can Start Any Virtual Device From Both Android Studio And Genymotion.