# Alternative android AVD for non supported processor

Tags: android, android-virtual-device

I m using android SDK on windows 8 enterprise.
I install android after installation when I start AVD its not running.
I install HAXM emulator from SDK manager. I also install it manually.
so I checked my **processor it does not support virtual technology.**
is there any alternative avd which can not require VT.
I find one alternative avd which is **genymotion** but I think it's also require VT.
can I install VT or any other way to check and test the android application.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, you can download and use `ARM images` that do not need hardware virtualization instead of using `x86 system images`. Need to tell you that ARM images will be very slow compared to x86 images.

You can download `ARM image` of respective APIs by selecting this option.

[image]

Comment: I installed it but how can I use it.

Comment: Go to your AVD Manager, and select the installed image and start it. After you can test your applications in Emulator.

Comment: i tried to run it and it shows error `could not initialize openIES emulation, use '-gpu off' to disable it` and there are many error in gradle console related to this.

Answer (score 0):

you can use genymotion to test your android applications,it's really fast. genymotion needs VT,so you can install Oracle VM VirtualBox to support.
[https://www.genymotion.com] it can lead you to install.

Comment: but in `System requirements: VT-x or AMD-V capable CPU` they write that.

Comment: @Mr. Dattani I see your answer but this slow method. Can I run `genymotion` without VT. How about if I install Virtualbox. Can virtualBox require VT for installation. Thanks...

Comment: Probably this could help, Disable VTx option from system settings of virtual box. Check @saurjk's answer here.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21757368/unable-to-start-genymotion-virtual-device-incompatible-cpu