# Genymotion Power up failed (vrc=VERR_SUPDRV_COMPONENT_NOT_FOUND, rc=E_FAIL (0X80004005))

Tags: virtual-machine, virtualbox, windows-7-x64, genymotion

I installed both virtual box 5.0.18 and Genymotion 2.8.1 on windows 7 a year ago and it was working till few weeks ago and all of sudden i get this error when trying to start Custom Phone -6.0.0 virtual device:

```
Unbale to start the virtual device
VirtualBox cannont start the virtual device.

To find out the ause of the problem.Start the virtual device from vitualbox.

For more information, check the log files.Please refer to :www.genymotion.com/faq/logs
```

[image]

when i tried to start the virtual device from Virtualbox i get this error:

```
Failed to open a session for the virtual machine Custom Phone - 6.0.0 - API 23 - 768x1280.

Failed to open/create the internal network 'HostInterfaceNetworking-VirtualBox Host-Only Ethernet Adapter' (VERR_SUPDRV_COMPONENT_NOT_FOUND).

Failed to attach the network LUN (VERR_SUPDRV_COMPONENT_NOT_FOUND).

Result Code: E_FAIL (0x80004005)
Component: ConsoleWrap
Interface: IConsole {872da645-4a9b-1614-bee2-5585105b9eed}
```

[image]

and this is part of genymotion log:

```
ERROR [COM]: aRC=E_FAIL (0x80004005) aIID={872da645-4a9b-1614-bee2-5585105b9eed} aComponent={ConsoleWrap} aText={Failed to open/create the internal network 'HostInterfaceNetworking-VirtualBox Host-Only Ethernet Adapter' (VERR_SUPDRV_COMPONENT_NOT_FOUND).
Failed to attach the network LUN (VERR_SUPDRV_COMPONENT_NOT_FOUND)}, preserve=false aResultDetail=0
Console: Machine state changed to 'PoweredOff'
Power up failed (vrc=VERR_SUPDRV_COMPONENT_NOT_FOUND, rc=E_FAIL (0X80004005))
```

[image]
I went to **File=>Preferences=>Network=>Host-only Networks** on virtualbox and deleted the **VirtualBox Host-only Ethernet Adapter** but still same error after genymotion re added it again!

could you guys help me fix the above problem without having to reinstall virtualbox and genymotion and losing all my virtual machines ?Thanks in advance.

Comment: I had the same problem, got it solved here, do check this link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21757368/unable-to-start-genymotion-virtual-device-incompatible-cpu